Resolving type conversion error for Keras functional model with categorical features of different datatypes
I am working on creating a model which imports a csv of categorical string and numeric data as well as continuous features to predict if a student will graduate.



Index
Age
Household_Size
Gender
Marital_Status
Occupation
Income_Level
Graduated




0
32
4
Female
Married
Nurse
60000
1


1
45
2
Male
Divorced
Teacher
80000
1


2
28
1
Female
Single
Software Engineer
120000
1


3
62
2
Male
Married
Retired
20000
1


4
35
3
Female
Married
Lawyer
160000
1



Layer creation function definitions
def get_normalization_layer(name, dataset):
  # Create a Normalization layer for the feature.
  norm=name+'_norm'
  normalizer = layers.Normalization(axis=None, name=norm)

  # Prepare a Dataset that only yields the feature.
  feature_ds = dataset.map(lambda x, y: x[name])

  # Learn the statistics of the data.
  normalizer.adapt(feature_ds)

  return normalizer

def get_category_encoding_layer(name, dataset, dtype, max_tokens=None):
  # Create a layer that turns strings into integer indices.
  ind=name+'_index'
  if dtype == 'string':
    index = layers.StringLookup(max_tokens=max_tokens, name=ind)
  # Otherwise, create a layer that turns integer values into integer indices.
  else:
    index = layers.IntegerLookup(max_tokens=max_tokens, name=ind)

  # Prepare a `tf.data.Dataset` that only yields the feature.
  feature_ds = dataset.map(lambda x, y: x[name])

  # Learn the set of possible values and assign them a fixed integer index.
  index.adapt(feature_ds)

  # Encode the integer indices.
  enc=name+'_encoding'
  encoder = layers.CategoryEncoding(num_tokens=index.vocabulary_size(), name=enc)

  # Apply multi-hot encoding to the indices. The lambda function captures the
  # layer, so you can use them, or include them in the Keras Functional model later.
  return lambda feature: encoder(index(feature))

Model Creation
all_inputs = []
encoded_features = []

categorical_str_cols = ['Gender', 'Marital_Status', 'Occupation']

for header in categorical_str_cols:
  categorical_col = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name=header, dtype='string')

  encoding_layer = get_category_encoding_layer(name=header,
                                               dataset=train_ds,
                                               dtype='string')
  encoded_categorical_str_col = encoding_layer(categorical_col)
  all_inputs.append(categorical_col)
  encoded_features.append(encoded_categorical_str_col)

categorical_int_cols = ['Age', 'Household_Size']

for header in categorical_int_cols:
  categorical_col = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name=header, dtype='int64')
  encoding_layer = get_category_encoding_layer(name=header,
                                               dataset=train_ds,
                                               dtype='int64')
  encoded_categorical_int_col = encoding_layer(categorical_col)
  all_inputs.append(categorical_col)
  encoded_features.append(encoded_categorical_int_col)

# Numerical features.
for header in ['Income_Level']:
  numeric_col = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name=header)
  normalization_layer = get_normalization_layer(header, train_ds)
  encoded_numeric_col = normalization_layer(numeric_col)
  all_inputs.append(numeric_col)
  encoded_features.append(encoded_numeric_col)

all_features = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(encoded_features)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu")(all_features)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(all_inputs, output)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=["accuracy"])

Model Image
Can't post image because rep is too low link:
Model Image from plot_model
When I go to run model.fit on a tf.dataset, I receive the error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[539], line 1
----> 1 model.fit(train_ds, epochs=10, validation_data=val_ds)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:53, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     51 try:
     52   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 53   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     54                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     55 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     56   if name is not None:

UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node functional_27_1/Cast defined at (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main

  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 1075, in launch_instance

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 701, in start

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 205, in start

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 322, in run_forever

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 641, in run_forever

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1987, in _run_once

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 88, in _run

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 534, in dispatch_queue

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 523, in process_one

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 429, in dispatch_shell

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 767, in execute_request

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 429, in do_execute

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 549, in run_cell

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3075, in run_cell

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3130, in _run_cell

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3334, in run_cell_async

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3517, in run_ast_nodes

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3577, in run_code

  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_5448\2809293729.py", line 1, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\tensorflow\trainer.py", line 318, in fit

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\tensorflow\trainer.py", line 121, in one_step_on_iterator

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\tensorflow\trainer.py", line 108, in one_step_on_data

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\tensorflow\trainer.py", line 51, in train_step

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\layer.py", line 882, in __call__

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 117, in error_handler

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\ops\operation.py", line 46, in __call__

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 156, in error_handler

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\functional.py", line 167, in call

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\functional.py", line 258, in _standardize_inputs

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\functional.py", line 218, in _convert_inputs_to_tensors

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\ops\core.py", line 743, in convert_to_tensor

  File "C:\Users\-\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\tensorflow\core.py", line 120, in convert_to_tensor

Cast int64 to string is not supported
     [[{{node functional_27_1/Cast}}]] [Op:__inference_one_step_on_iterator_97454]

Example tf.dataset batch size 3
{'Age': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[23],
       [29],
       [31]], dtype=int64)>, 'Household_Size': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[3],
       [3],
       [3]], dtype=int64)>, 'Gender': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1), dtype=string, numpy=
array([[b'Female'],
       [b'Female'],
       [b'Female']], dtype=object)>, 'Marital_Status': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1), dtype=string, numpy=
array([[b'Single'],
       [b'Single'],
       [b'Single']], dtype=object)>, 'Occupation': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1), dtype=string, numpy=
array([[b'Server'],
       [b'Nurse'],
       [b'Retail Associate']], dtype=object)>, 'Income_Level': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[30000],
       [50000],
       [30000]], dtype=int64)>}
tf.Tensor([1 1 1], shape=(3,), dtype=int64)

However, if I either exclude the string categorical layers and data, or only use the string layers/data the model successfully runs its training. How should I be creating the layers so that I can have both dtypes in the same model?
